# Progress dialog not dismiss after (progress == 100) in webview

Tags: android, webview, progressdialog

progressdialog not dismiss after page loading, here what i am missing

```
 final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Webview.this );
WebView webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewID);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    //webview.loadData(content, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    webview.loadUrl("http://hop.betfanplus.com/10000/0/mega4");

    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
          @Override
          public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
             // progressDialog.show();
             ProgressDialog
                      .show(Webview.this,
                              "ProgressDialog Title",
                                  "ProgressDialog Body");

              if (progress == 100) {
                 progressDialog.dismiss();               
                 }
          }
      });
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are using the class itself within onProgresschange instead of the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still use onPageStarted and onPageFinished.

From my experience, using progress percentage will reach 100 even if the webpage fails to load, so that won't work.

```
boolean loadingFinished = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Webview.this );
    progressDialog.setMessage("ProgressDialog Body");
    progressDialog.show();
    WebView webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewID);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            loadingFinished = false;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            loadingFinished = true;
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }

    });
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.loadUrl("http://hop.betfanplus.com/10000/0/mega4");


}
```

Comment: pls tell me solution according my code if possible, i don't want use onPageStarted and onPageFinished @html tosin

Comment: can we discuss some more issues in chat? @Html Tosin

Comment: Sure, you can send me a link

Comment: i don't know how to send please you can send me link of chat @Html Tosin

Answer (score 0):

In my experience , is to declare the webview and then the progressDialog with the webview context in oncreate Method as it is shown here:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(webView.getContext(), R.style.CustomAlertDialogStyle);

}
```

Then set the setWebCrhomeListener

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (!progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
                progressDialog.setProgress(progress);
           

        });
}
```

Then control the Dialog show() and dismiss() in onPageFinished() and onPageStarted()

```
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
```